# getting a tuple subset with lens over a ReaderT

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I would like to play with tuples and lens this way :

```
myfct :: ReaderT (a,b,c,d,e) m a -> ReaderT (a,c,d) m a
myfct = zoom ...
```

be able to modify the input tuple to a subset of it...

pseudo code would be something like this :

```
zoom (_1,_3,_4)
```

Comment: Really not sure what you mean, but you probably are looking for `magnify` and not `zoom`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @dfeuer notes, you probably meant to write:

```
myfct' :: Monad m => ReaderT (a,c,d) m a -> ReaderT (a,b,c,d,e) m a
```

This takes an action that only requires access to the context `(a,c,d)` and lifts it to an action that can run in a larger context that supplies `(a,b,c,d,e)`.  This can be written using `magnify` like so:

```
myfct' = magnify . to $ \(a,_,c,d,_) -> (a,c,d)
```

On the other hand, if you actually meant what you wrote:

```
myfct :: Monad m => ReaderT (a,b,c,d,e) m a -> ReaderT (a,c,d) m a
```

then you're going to have to explain what this is supposed to do.  In particular, if you have an action that accesses the `b :: String` component:

```
action :: Reader (Int,String,Int,Int,Int) Int
action = asks $ \(_,b,_,_,_) -> length (b :: String)
```

How do you want to run it in a context with no `b :: String`?

```
test' :: Int
test' = runReader (myfct action) (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

[K. A. Buhr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59887458/2751851) perfectly suffices, so here goes just a little tidbit. Since `magnify` need just a getter (rather than a full-blown lens) one might express `myfct'` in terms of `_1` and friends with the help of [`ReifiedGetter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.18.1/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html#t:ReifiedGetter):

```
myfct' :: Monad m => ReaderT (a,c,d) m a -> ReaderT (a,b,c,d,e) m a
myfct' = magnify (runGetter $ (,,) <$> Getter _1 <*> Getter _3 <*> Getter _4)
```

Though not particularly ergonomic, this is perhaps a bit closer to the spirit of your pseudocode.